# Wordpress pagination prev/next arrows

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress pagination works but I'd like to make some 'minor' adjustments. I thought I'd be able to find some code I could drop into my functions.php but I can't find anything that does the job, so I'm hoping for a bit of help.

Basically I want the pagination to always display the prev/next arrows, whichever one isn't needed has a class of inactive for styling - currently whichever isn't required isn't displayed at all. Also, I'd like to know if '...' is added between a range of pages if they exceed a certain amount to prevent the list from getting too long?

Here's the current code I have in functions.php:

```
function html5wp_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ));
}
```

Hope someone can help. I'm getting there with Wordpress/PHP development but somethings still look totally foreign to me!

Answer (score 3):

Update Your pagination code like below:

```
echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'show_all' => False,
        'prev_next' => True,
        'prev_text' => __('&lt;'),
        'next_text' => __('&gt;'),
        'type'      => 'list',
        'add_args' => ''
    ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do I need to wrap that in a function so I can call it in the templates like `<?php get_template_part('paginate_links'); ?>`?

Comment: yes, just replace your echo paginate_links(... function with answer and check it.

Comment: I did that but on the first page the previous arrow isn't visible until I navigation to page 2. I could check that by pasting over the code in my parent theme functions.php but if I put it in my child theme it breaks because `html5wp_pagination` is already in use (by the parent). If I change the name it update doesn't go on the page. Is this because it's a 'global' function? The call in my php template is `<?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>` and I can't see 'pagination' referenced anywhere in functions.php?